# Auto-hide Unity Top Bar

Tags: unity

I'd like Unity top bar to be hidden, and only appear when the mouse reaches the top of the screen. How do I do that?

Comment: Afaik, you can't, there is no setting nor cli option to do that (without breaking into the code).

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

Unfortunately, there is no option in `gsettings`, nor anywhere else, nor a cli option to do what you want.

That is, without breaking into the code of course.